# Why images no get new position in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position

I created a circle and I add circumferential objects.
[image]

This is a example image. The arrows that lead to the center are the positions that I need. Position, Rotation, Scale.

Now I've made a script that randomises a single number (0...5) (positions).
Then another random, from 0 to 11 (elements) (which position to take).

Next, in these positions I already add a new element.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Respawn : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform[] Points;
public Image[] Images;

int Count; 

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Randomize ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void Randomize() {
    Count = Random.Range (0, 5);
    for (int i = 0; i <= Count; i++) {
        int Selected;
        Selected = Random.Range (0, 11);
        Selector (Selected);
    }
}

void Selector(int id) {
    Images [id].transform.position = Points [id].transform.position;
    Images [id].transform.rotation = Points [id].transform.rotation;
    Images [id].transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.1f,0.1f);
    Instantiate (Images [id], Points [id], Points [id]);

    Debug.Log ("Point - " + Points [id].transform.position);
    Debug.Log ("Image - " + Images [id].transform.position);
    Debug.Log ("\n");
}
}
```

It does not work, but I think I just want to add pictures and just already disable or enable them

Comment: why it doesn't work? what it's your actual output? You got log error? where are the images spawn?

Comment: When I look at your Instantiate-command, you use a Transform-Object as 2nd and 3th parameter. In the docs (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) there's no overload that takes those kind of elements. Maybe this could cause your problems?